# Comparar hora de un dato en mysql con la hora actual en PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, time

Tengo un problema entre manos, les comento:

Estoy trabajando en PHP, MySQL y Javascript

Tengo una base de datos para organizar la atención a tickets de soporte técnico de una empresa, pero me gustaría mandar una alerta si el estatus o actualización de un ticket no cambia cada 15 minutos.

Es decir, necesito comparar todos los campos con la hora de actualización (ultima llamada en la tabla) con la hora actual y si hay una diferencia de 15 minutos me envíe una alerta en pantalla.

Yo lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

En un PHP generé una tabla de consulta a partir de la prioridad que tiene cada ticket

```
<?php
$users= array(); 
$sql = "SELECT update_at FROM ticket WHERE priority_id=1 AND status_id=2"; 
$users = TicketData::getBySQL($sql);
if(count($users)>0){ // si hay usuarios ?>
```

Y despúes lo mandé a una tabla

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable(); 
} );
</script>
<table id="example" class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
<thead><tr>
    <th>Destino</th>
    <th>Ecomonico</th>
    <th>Ultima Llamada</th>
    <th></th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
        foreach($users as $user){
        $project  = $user->getProject();
        $medic = $user->getPriority();
    ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $user->title; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $user->getCategory()->name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $user->updated_at; ?></td>
    <td style="width:80px;">
        <a href="index.php?view=editticket&id=<?php echo $user->id;?>" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Editar</a>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>

<?php
}
    ?> 
 </table> 
<?php
    }else{
    echo "<p class='alert alert-danger'>No hay fletes</p>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: [Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Este no es un sitio para solicitar código. Para que la comunidad entienda mejor su pregunta, debe leer [cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Luego [edit] la pregunta.

Comment: Gracias Mauricio, ya agregué el código que tengo para poder trabajar sobre él

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La sentencia SQL debería ser algo así:

```
SELECT timestampdiff(MINUTE, update_at, now()) <= 15
  FROM ticket
 WHERE priority_id=1 AND status_id=2
```

Realmente lo que hacemos con esta sentencia es obtener los resultados de aquellos tickets en los que la fecha de actualización es igual o superior a 15 minutos.

Comment: Hola Dismark, voy a intentar agregar esto y luego lanzar un script condicional para la alerta, muchas gracias!

Comment: Esta fue la sentencia que use para que en lugar de condicionar las acciones con un IF le dijera al sistema exactamente que es lo que quiero que me muestre.
`$sql = "SELECT * FROM ticket 
WHERE timestampdiff(MINUTE, updated_at, now()) >= 15 
AND priority_id=1 AND status_id=2 
ORDER BY `ticket`.`updated_at` DESC";`

Answer (score 1):

***Resuelto***
Quiero agradecer a los usuarios que se dieron el tiempo de responder mi duda

Utilizando dentro de PHP la sentencia:

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE timestampdiff(MINUTE, updated_at, now()) >= 15 AND` 
`priority_id=1 AND status_id=2 ORDER BY ticket.updated_at DESC";`

Pude hacer la comparación de tiempos y sin necesidad de imponer alguna condicional, esto se pudo adaptar a la perfección a mis necesidades, espero que le sirva a alguien mas.