# Como comparar fecha y hora php

Tags: php, date, horas

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que estoy en php y estoy creando un formulario el cual es para recuperar contraseña, una vez enviado el formulario creo un token el cual es generado de esta forma:

```
function generateRandomInt($length = 6) {
    $characters = '0123456789';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;

}
```

Con eso lo que busco hacer es que genere una cadena con 6 caracteres, y un caracter puede tener un numero aleatorio entre el 0 y el 9, de esa forma creo mis tokens, lo siguiente es que tengo una base de datos en la cual guardo el id del token, el token, la fecha en la que expira y el email del usuario que solicito el reinicio de contraseña, (el como recibo el email es porque antes ejecuto una consulta con el email que me llega por post para ver si el email existe y si si existe va a seguir ejecutando el procedimiento del restablecimiento de contraseña), por lo que mi tabla queda de esta forma:

```
CREATE TABLE reset_password_token(
id              int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
token           INT not null,
expired_at      TIMESTAMP not null,
user_email      varchar(30) not null,
CONSTRAINT pk_reset_password_token PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Ahora con esa informacion dada esta es la forma en la que creo el token completo:

```
 $token =  generateRandomInt(); //Generar token

//Generar fecha de expiración del token

$tomorrow = date('d') + 1;
$expired_at = date("Y-m-$tomorrow h:i:s");


$newToken = new Token();
$newToken->setToken($token);
$newToken->setExpired_at($expired_at);
$newToken->setUser_email($email);
$newToken->save();
```

Ahora antes de seguir este es mi codigo de la clase `Token`:

```
class Token
{
    private $token;
    private $expired_at;
    private $user_email;
    public $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new mysql('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of token
     *
     * @return  self
     */ 
    public function setToken($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of expired_at
     *
     * @return  self
     */ 
    public function setExpired_at($expired_at)
    {
        $this->expired_at = $expired_at;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of user_email
     *
     * @return  self
     */ 
    public function setUser_email($user_email)
    {
        $this->user_email = $user_email;

        return $this;
    }

    //Inserta el nuevo token
    public function save(): void
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO reset_password_token VALUES(null, {$this->token}, '{$this->expired_at}', '{$this->user_email}')");
    }
}
```

Como pueden ver es un código relativamente básico de una consulta sql y de algunos metodos setter, lo siguiente es que una vez hecho esto lo que hago es que le envio un correo al usuario con el token generado y lo redirijo a la página en la que tiene que escribir su token, y ahora mi duda es ¿cómo puedo comparar la fecha de expiración del token con la fecha en la que el usuario escribe el codigo? es decir que como se ve en mi código lo que hago es que el token expira en 24 horas al dia siguiente pero como puedo comparar la fecha y hora para ver si el usuario esta restableciendo su contraseña antes de la fecha de expiración y actuar en base a ello, también quiero saber como puedo hacer que se borre el token despues de la fecha de expiración sin hacer la consulta para ver si el token existe pero creo que esa duda no queda con este tema del todo (aunque igual si alguien me puede ayudar en esto último lo agradecería), entonces en resumen mi duda es ¿cómo puedo comparar dos campos con fecha y hora para ver si uno se ejecuta antes que el otro?. Desde ya gracias y espero haberme dado a entender. por ultimo esta es la forma en la que veo la fecha del usuario actual:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
```

Ahora si desde ya gracias a todos. Saludos

### Edit

Intente hacerlo con la función `NOW()`, e inserte valores en la tabla con la misma funcion para que caducara en el pasado, si no me explique bien aquí hay una captura de pantalla de lo que hice:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y como pueden ver abajo donde selecciono los registros me devuelve todos, sin importar su fecha, el código lo hice con:

```
SELECT * FROM reset_password_token WHERE NOW() > expired_at
```

Por que si lo hacía con:

```
SELECT * FROM reset_password_token WHERE NOW() < expired_at
```

Me devuelve la siguiente salida:

```
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Agradezco si alguien me dice que estoy haciendo mal al seleccionar los datos, o el como debo hacerlo. Otra vez gracias :).

Comment: Las cadenas representando fechas las puedes comparar con los operadores >, <, >=, <=, tanto en PHP como en SQL. ¿Te referías a eso? Sirve para formato date y formato datetime.

Comment: No es necesario comparar la fecha en PHP, simplemente en la consulta busca el token y que la fecha sea mayor o igual que la actual. Puedes usar la función `NOW()` de MySQL. También sería buena idea eliminar los tokens expirados, tal vez con una tarea programada.

Comment: @Triby y Jóse Carlos PHP actualice la pregunta con lo que ambos me dijeron, ya que me devuelve algo raro, agradezco su ayuda :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias forma de hacerlo.

1. Hacerlo con el Query ([documentacion.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/237898/comparar-hora-de-un-dato-en-mysql-con-la-hora-actual-en-php?rq=1)):

Validara si el toque caduco pasado X cantidad de minutos; esto puedes adaptarlo a tu necesidad.

```
SELECT *, timestampdiff(MINUTE, update_at, now()) <= 15 
  FROM reset_password_token;
```

2. El otro método es hacer la comparación en tu lado de php con `strtotime` ([Documentacion](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php)):

```php
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$expire = $row->expireDate; //from database

$today_time = strtotime($today);
$expire_time = strtotime($expire);

if ($expire_time < $today_time) { 
    /* do Something */
}
```

o bien con `DateTime` ([Documentacion](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php)):

```php
$today_dt = new DateTime($today);
$expire_dt = new DateTime($expire);

if ($expire_dt < $today_dt) { 
    /* Do something */ 
}
```

***tu código quedaría de la siguiente forma:***

```php
$token =  generateRandomInt(); //Generar token

//Generar fecha de expiración del token

//$tomorrow = date('d') + 1;
//$expired_at = date("Y-m-$tomorrow h:i:s");

$expired_at = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 day"));


$newToken = new Token();
$newToken->setToken($token);
$newToken->setExpired_at($expired_at);
$newToken->setUser_email($email);
$newToken->save();
```

y luego en tu query puede ser así:

```
SELECT * 
FROM reset_password_token 
WHERE
    token = 123456 
    AND expired_at >= NOW();
```

pero aquí no acaba todo ya que tienes que validar si la consulta fue correcta, yo utilizaría `num_rows` [Documentacion](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php).

```
if($result->num_rows==1){
        /* Do something */ 
}
```

Comment: Hola intente como lo dijiste tanto con sql y php y funciono, muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

Debes crear tu consulta para obtener el token ingresado por el usuario y que la fecha de expiración sea mayor o igual que la actual, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM reset_password_token
WHERE
    token = 123456 AND expired_at >= NOW();
```

Si la fecha y hora de expiración es menor que la actual, quiere decir que el token ya caducó.

En las consultas no estás obteniendo registros porque guardas con la fecha actual, pero debes agregar el tiempo que deseas de vigencia para el token, usando [DATE_ADD()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add), por ejemplo:

```
INSERT INTO reset_password_token
VALUES (987654, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY), 'user@correo.com');
```

Comment: Triby intente como lo dijiste pero me sigue dando resultados vacios, pero no pude encontrar porque :(